# Duda con generadores, obtener un item previo

Tags: python, python-3.x, generador

Estoy aprendiendo Python por mi cuenta y me surge una duda con el uso de los generadores.

Se supone que un generador te crea un elemento iterable que te irá mostrando los resultados uno a uno, ¿no?

Os pongo este ejemplo de código para explicar mi duda:

```
def generador(): # Generará una lista infinita de números pares, una a uno, cada vez que se llame al generador.
    i = 1
    while i != 0: # Condición infinita.
        yield i * 2 #Devuele el resultado a un objeto iterable.
        i += 1 # Sumamos un 1 más a nuestra variable.

objeto_iterable = generador() # Convertimos esta variable en un objeto iterable.
```

Ahora bien, puedo ir llamando uno a uno los elementos con `next()`, pero si necesito un resultado previo, ¿Cómo accedo a él?

Por ejemplo, llamo al generador 5 veces, pero luego necesito el resultado que me dio en la segunda llamada, ¿Cómo accedo a ese resultado?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta corta es **de ninguna forma sin usar algún objeto externo al propio generador que actúe e contenedor**, cuando se itera sobre un generador se podría decir coloquialmente que los items "se consumen". Los generadores son de una sola pasada, obteniendo cada elemento a petición.

`yield`/`yield from` permite crear una función generadora. Dichas funciones devuelven un objeto generador. Básicamente los pasos que sigue un generador son:

- Cuando se llama por primera vez a su método `__next__` se ejecuta el código hasta que se llega a `yield`. En ese momento se retorna lo que yield especifique y la ejecución queda en pausa, con el estado actual guardado en memoria.
- Al volver a llamar a `__next__` se vuelve a retornar el código donde se dejó hasta que se encuentre otro `yield`. Generalmente se suele usar un ciclo con `yield` dentro. En este punto se procede igual que antes, se retorna lo que `yield` especifique y la ejecución se pausa (sin bloquear), manteniendo el estado, a la espera de otra posible llamada a `__next__`.
- El punto anterior se repite hasta que por la causa que sea (generalmente se cumple la condición de salida del ciclo) la ejecución del código termina sin llegar a ninguna expresión con `yield`. A partir de este momento, toda llamada a `__next__` ocasiona una excepción de tipo `StopIteration`.

Si se entiende lo anterior, es fácil entender que lo único que un generador almacena en memoria es su estado (por ejemplo variables locales) para poder continuar a partir de ahí si se vuelve a iterar sobre él. En ningún momento almacena los items que va generando, lo que implica que a diferencia de otros iteradores, solo son iterables una vez,y por supuesto no son indizables.

Esta es precisamente la gracia de los generadores, permiten crear un iterable e ir obteniendo items a petición (llamadas a `__next__`) **sin necesidad de crear y almacenar dichos items** en su conjunto y de forma concurrente en memoria.  Un **nuevo item solo se genera cuando se necesita**, por eso se dice que los generadores son "perezosos".

Los generadores además permiten recibir valores entre cada item generado mediante su método `send`, aunque esto se sale ya de la pregunta. Esta característica, junto a que retorna valores a demanda, **no bloqueando el hilo entre llamadas a `__next__`**, son la base de las corrutinas realmente (similar a lo que se conoce como hilos ligeros o hilos verdes en otros lenguajes)

Si necesitas un elemento previo y al final vas iterar  sobre todo el generador y vas a necesitar todos sus items, puedes iterar completamente sobre él y almacenarlos en un objeto contenedor iterable como una lista e indizar normalmente:

```
items = list(generador())
```

Odviamente, con ello perdemos la utilidad de un generador. De cualquier forma, en tu caso no puedes usar una lista ni cualquier otro contenedor para guardar todos los elementos retornados por el generador porque tu generador es infinito, consumirías toda la memoria disponible sin más. Si podría usar una lista o variables para guardar algunos items que te interesen o todos los generados hasta el momento:

```
def divisores(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if not n % i:
            yield i
```

> ```
> >>> divs = list(divisores(21))
> >>> divs
> [1, 3, 7, 21]
>
> >>> for div in divisores(12):
>         print(div)
>
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 6
> 12
> ```

```
gen = divisores(12)


aux = []
for n in range(3):
    div = next(gen)
    aux.append(div)
```

> ```
> >>> print(aux[2])    
> 3
> ```

Puestos a ser "rebuscados", podemos incluso ir poblando la lista en el propio generador y retornarla a ella o una copia en cada llamada a `__next__`. Posible es, que sea recomendable es discutible, aunque como en todo hay casos y casos, Python simplemente nos deja hacer, sean muy buenas ideas o muy malas...

```
def divisores(n):
    divs = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if not n % i:
            divs.append(i)
            yield divs.copy()

gen = divisores(12)
for n in range(5):
    divs = next(gen)
```

> ```
> >>> print(divs[2])
> 3
> >>> print(divs)
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
> ```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

¡Muchas gracias por la aclaración!

Tomando en cuenta lo que has comentado, he llegado a esta solución:

```
def Iterador():
    n = 1
    while n != 0:
        yield n * 2
        n += 1

ob=Iterador()
lista = list()
lista.append(next(ob))
print(lista)
```

Aunque no es la mejor del mundo. Bueno, solo quería saber cómo funcionaba yield por si alguna vez me hacía falta acceder a un dato anterior.

Gracias ;).