# Extraer informacion de archivo txt

Tags: python

Saludos tengo un archivo txt con informacion de usuarios como nombres, direcciones, etc a la cual intento acceder desde python algo asi:

```
def encontrar_ruc(file):
    for line in file:
        if '1804464194001' in line:
             yield line

source = open('TUNGURAHUA.txt','rb')
result = encontrar_ruc(source)
print(result)
```

al hacer esto me retorna:

```
<generator object encontrar_ruc at 0x7f665712fcd0>
```

bien si itero esto:

```
for r in result:
  print r
```

obtengo algo asi:

```
1804464195001   LOACHAMIN AVILA DIEGO ALBERTO       ACTIVO  OTROS   28/09/2015  29/01/2018      29/01/2018  N   PERSONAS NATURALES   1      MANUEL CAN  S/N BRASIL  ABI TUNGURAHUA  AMBATO  PICAIGUA    J620210 ACTIVIDADES DE PLANIFICACI�N Y DISE�O DE SISTEMAS INFORM�TICOS QUE INTEGRAN EQUIPO Y PROGRAMAS INFORM�TICOS Y TECNOLOG�A DE LAS COMUNICACIONES.
```

dicho resultado esta bien se puede apreciar que esta separado por espacios quiza alguna forma de acceder a esta informacion trate con result[0] pero me sale error:

> TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

ejemplos de datos del archivo:

```
NUMERO_RUC  RAZON_SOCIAL    NOMBRE_COMERCIAL    ESTADO_CONTRIBUYENTE    CLASE_CONTRIBUYENTE FECHA_INICIO_ACTIVIDADES    FECHA_ACTUALIZACION FECHA_SUSPENSION_DEFINITIVA FECHA_REINICIO_ACTIVIDADES  OBLIGADO    TIPO_CONTRIBUYENTE  NUMERO_ESTABLECIMIENTO  NOMBRE_FANTASIA_COMERCIAL   CALLE   NUMERO  INTERSECCION    ESTADO_ESTABLECIMIENTO  DESCRIPCION_PROVINCIA   DESCRIPCION_CANTON  DESCRIPCION_PARROQUIA   CODIGO_CIIU ACTIVIDAD_ECONOMICA
0100037647001   VELALCAZAR TAMAYO NELSON FERNANDO       PASIVO  OTROS   03/06/1994  15/06/2015  07/02/2018      N   PERSONAS NATURALES   1  MINI SUPER V.G. RUMINAHUI   07-105  SHYRIS  CER TUNGURAHUA  AMBATO  CELIANO MONGE   L682002 INTERMEDIACIÓN EN LA COMPRA, VENTA Y ALQUILER DE BIENES INMUEBLES A CAMBIO DE UNA RETRIBUCIÓN O POR CONTRATO.
0100037647001   VELALCAZAR TAMAYO NELSON FERNANDO       PASIVO  OTROS   03/06/1994  15/06/2015  07/02/2018      N   PERSONAS NATURALES   2      PACCHA  S/N AV. RUMIÑAHUI   CER TUNGURAHUA  AMBATO  HUACHI LORETO   L682002 INTERMEDIACIÓN EN LA COMPRA, VENTA Y ALQUILER DE BIENES INMUEBLES A CAMBIO DE UNA RETRIBUCIÓN O POR CONTRATO.
0100242593001   CORTEZ CARRANCO FRANCISCO       ACTIVO  OTROS   01/08/1969  17/05/2017      21/05/2008  N   PERSONAS NATURALES   1      FRESAS  01-74   AV. LOS GUAYTAMBOS  ABI TUNGURAHUA  AMBATO  ATOCHA - FICOA  L682002 INTERMEDIACIÓN EN LA COMPRA, VENTA Y ALQUILER DE BIENES INMUEBLES A CAMBIO DE UNA RETRIBUCIÓN O POR CONTRATO.
```

quiza alguna sugerencia gracias de antemano.!!

Comment: El espacio no puede ser un separador de columnas, seguramente vas a tener columnas de `RAZON_SOCIAL` compuestas por más de una palabra. Tal vez sea un tab?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho efectivamente al parecer es tab como separador..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu función `encontrar_ruc()` retorna un generador, lo cual es bueno. Un generador es un objeto que expresa ciertos datos de forma diferida, en tu caso la lista de las líneas dónde se ha encontrado un determinado `RUC`.

Recién cuando iteras sobre el generador o lo conviertes expresamente a una lista, es cuando podrás acceder a los valores, pero de cualquier forma, estos valores siguen siendo una cadena que representa la línea completa y lo que buscas es acceder de alguna forma a las columnas individuales.

Por lo que podrías usar el método `str.split('\t')` para separar cada columna y armar una lista de estas.

```
registros = list(linea.split('\t') for linea in encontrar_ruc(source))
```

Esto te debería retornar una lista de listas, por lo que acceder a los elementos individuales es más sencillo:

```
print(registros[0])    # Imprimimos la lista corresp. a la primer fila
print(registros[0][0]) # Imprimimos la columna 1 de la primer fila
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias ha funcionado de maravilla..!!

Answer (score 1):

Probá de esta manera:

```
def encontrar_ruc(file):
    for line in file.readlines():
        if '1804464194001' in line:
             yield line

source = open('TUNGURAHUA.txt','r')
result = encontrar_ruc(source)
print(result)
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero se obtiene el mismo resultado "<generator object encontrar_ruc at 0x7f0c53a2bcd0>
"

Comment: No se bien como tenés que implementar esto pero otra posibilidad sería:    `f = open('TUNGURAHUA.txt','r')
while(True):
    linea = f.readline()
 if '1804464194001' in linea:
  print linea
    if not linea:
        break
f.close()`

Answer (score 1):

Primero, te imprime:

> ```
> <generator object encontrar_ruc at 0x7f665712fcd0>
> ```

porque tu función al hacer uso de `yield` retorna un [generador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/277326/15089). Un generador no es indizable, para obtener cada fila debes iterar sobre el con un `for in`, llamar a su método `__next__()` o usarlo para construir una lista o otro objeto indizable.

Dado que lo que tienes en un csv, considera usar el módulo `csv` de la biblioteca estándar:

- Retornando una lista por fila con los valores de cada columna:

  ```
  import csv

  def encontrar_ruc(file, ruc):
      with open(file) as csvfile:
          reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
          for row in reader:
             if row[0] == ruc:
                 yield  row

  registros = list(encontrar_ruc('TUNGURAHUA.txt', "1804464195001"))
  ```

  Con ello obtendrás algo como:

  ```
  [
   ["1804464195001", "LOACHAMIN AVILA DIEGO ALBERTO", "", "ACTIVO", ...],
   ["1804464195001", "LOACHAMIN AVILA DIEGO ALBERTO", "", "ACTIVO", ...]
  ]
  ```

  Una lista con las filas que cumplen el criterio. Cada fila es una lista con los valores para cada columna. Para acceder al valor de una columna debes indizar en la lista:

  > ```
  > >>> print(registros[0][1]) # Primera fila que coincide, columna 1
  > LOACHAMIN AVILA DIEGO ALBERTO
  > ```
- Retornando un diccionario por cada fila en la que las claves son el nombre de la columna:

  ```
  def encontrar_ruc(file, ruc):
      with open(file) as csvfile:
          reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
          for row in reader:
              if row["NUMERO_RUC"] == ruc:
                  yield row

  registros = list(encontrar_ruc('TUNGURAHUA.txt', "1804464195001"))
  ```

  En este caso obtiene una listas con un diccionario por cada fila que cumpla el criterio:

  ```
  [
   {'NUMERO_RUC': "1804464195001", 'RAZON_SOCIAL': "LOACHAMIN AVILA DIEGO ALBERTO", 'NOMBRE_COMERCIAL': '', 'ESTADO_CONTRIBUYENTE': 'ACTIVO'},
   {'NUMERO_RUC': "1804464195001", 'RAZON_SOCIAL': "LOACHAMIN AVILA DIEGO ALBERTO", 'NOMBRE_COMERCIAL': '', 'ESTADO_CONTRIBUYENTE': 'ACTIVO'}
  ]
  ```

  Por lo que puedes acceder al valor de la fila para una columna dada usando el nombre de la columna:

  > ```
  > >>> print(registros[0]["RAZON_SOCIAL"])
  > LOACHAMIN AVILA DIEGO ALBERTO
  > ```

En ambos casos he dejado que la función siga siendo una función generadora, ya que esto puede serte útil para poder iterar sobre las filas que cumplen el criterio sin tener que construir una lista, lo cual preserva memoria:

```
for row in encontrar_ruc('TUNGURAHUA.txt', "1804464195001"):
    print(row["RAZON_SOCIAL"])
```